# Archiving github projects - collaborators

Tags: github

Supposing that I want to archive some old GitHub project:

- Are project collaborators notified upon my action?
- Will the project be archived for every other collaborator as well?

Answer (score 1):

1. The collaborators will not directly be notified about your action
2. Yes, the whole repository will be archived for everyone. The collaborators will still be free to fork or star the repository.